# Create same control of one already declared

Tags: c#, instance, groupbox

I have found in an old topic this:

```
object newobject = Activator.CreateInstance(comboBox1.GetType);
```

but doesn't work:

> The best overloaded method match for System.Activator.CreateInstance(System.Type, params object[]) has some invalid arguments

The problem is I have this :
http://it.tinypic.com/r/mtpcih/8

The group box is declared, not dynamically, I want to if I click the button Add one Field 
a new group box equal to the first one (Fields 1) appear.

At the form load event, I can create an instance of array of group box to make easier the access to data on text box?

I hope that someone can help me.

Comment: it should be better to create a usercontrol with that design(groupbox with those controls inside),and then add a new instance of it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
object newobjcet = Activator.CreateInstance(comboBox1.GetType());
```

You are missing the braces.

Comment: now I get that : this.Controls.Add(newobject); cannot convert object in control, how can i fix?

Comment: @user3289840 Cast it to `Control`.